# OTP - Adding Couchbeam as a dependency - ** exception error: undefined function jsx:decode/1

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, relx

I'm using rebar to get/compile my dependencies which has the following in `rebar.conf`:

```
{deps, [
    ...
    {couchbeam, ".*", {git, "git://github.com/benoitc/couchbeam.git", {branch, "master"}}}
  ]}.
```

then I use relx to generate the release. relx.config has:

```
{release, {myapp, "0.0.1"}, [myapp, couchbeam]}.
{extended_start_script, true}.
```

myapp.app.src:

```
{application, myapp,
 [                             
  {description, ""},           
  {vsn, "1"},
  {registered, []},            
  {applications, [             
                  kernel,      
                  stdlib,  

                  ... ,

                  couchbeam    
                 ]},
  {mod, { myapp_app, []}},    
  {env, []}
 ]}.
```

having started couchdb, I run my release under console and try to test couchbeam with the following lines:

```
Host = "localhost",
Port = 5984,
Prefix = "",
Options = [],
S = couchbeam:server_connection(Host, Port, Prefix, Options).
{ok, _Version} = couchbeam:server_info(S).
```

the last line gives me the error:
`** exception error: undefined function jsx:decode/1`

---

To solve this, I opened `deps/couchbeam/couchbeam.app.src` and changed:

```
 {applications, [kernel,
                  stdlib,
                  asn1,
                  crypto,
                  public_key,
                  ssl,
                  idna,
                  hackney
                  ]},
```

and added jsx:

```
{applications, [kernel,
                  stdlib,
                  asn1,
                  crypto,
                  public_key,
                  ssl,
                  idna,
                  hackney,
                  jsx
                  ]},
```

Is there something wrong in my setup of how I added couchbeam as a dependency? I feel like I'm not supposed to hack the .app.src of one of my dependencies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is that couchbeam doesn't include `jsx` as application-level dendency (in `.app.src` file) because it can work with different json encoders (actually only with `jsx` and `jiffy`). So, you should decide which one exactly to use by your own.

Since neither couchbeam nor your application doesn't provide any information about this depedency, `relx` doesn't include `jsx` in release.

Confess, I didn't try, but I think your solution is to define `jsx` as dependency of your own application (i.e., add it to your own `.app.src` file instead of `couchbeam.app.src`).

Comment: i see. I actually went with jiffy and added in `{erl_opts, [{d, 'WITH_JIFFY'}]}.` to the `rebar.config`. I overlooked that note about jiffy at first in the docs. But yeah, I see that it may have been better to add jsx to my own `.app.src`, Thanks!